# Can microsoft .net core 2.2 sdk docker container be used for building 2.1 and 2.2 targeted projects

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have several .net core 2.1 and 2.2 projects that will be built using on-premises servers that run Docker containers for the build workspaces. I am planning to use the **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1** image to build the 2.1 projects, and the **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2** image to build the 2.2 projects, but I'd like to simplify things if I can. Is it advisable to use just the **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2** image to build both 2.1 and 2.2 projects, and get rid of the 2.1 sdk image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following from Microsoft on their [Prerequisites for .NET Core on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) page. This page specifically relates to Visual Studio, but note the verbiage regarding the 2.2 SDK:

> Once you have Visual Studio configured with ***.NET Core 2.2 SDK***, you can
>   do the following actions:
>
> - Open, ***build***, and run existing .NET Core 1.x ***and 2.x projects***.
> - Retarget .NET Core 1.x and 2.x projects to .NET Core 2.2, build, and    run.
> - Create new .NET Core 2.2 projects.

According to the above quoted section of the docs, you should be able to safely build your 2.x projects in the 2.2 SDK container and shouldn't need the 2.1 SDK container for 2.1 project builds.